# Multi-dimensional (2D) Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, syntax

I tried to read about arrays and their syntax.it seems there is only a one way to type a 2-d array into a code. so I wanted to make sure before proceeding.So, is it possible to write 2-d array in a different syntax other than array[i][j]?

**example: if i have array[4][4], is it possible to type array[16] instead of the usual way? is it considered as a 2-d array?**

Comment: `double pointer` means pointer to a pointer can works like a 2D array.

Answer (score 2):

Note that modelling a 2-d array that allows you to index using `[][]` suffers from

1. The edge is jagged; you can have different rows with different lengths.
2. The memory is fragmented which can cause problems with performance.

An alternative is to use a contiguous block and use `row * i + j` notation to access the element at `(i, j)`. Encoding that in a function is idiomatic.

So I'd advise doing the latter. You can always switch the *implementation* back to jagged memory should you need to; retaining the function prototypes that you've already written.

Comment: This answer is completely misleading. Real 2D arrays in C have rows with exactly the same length and are allocated contiguously. You are probably referring to arrays of pointers that can be used as some sort of pseudo array. But using such a thing would be very bad advice for a programming novice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the recommended and the proper way of creating the 2D array is `array[4][4]` which means like `array[row][column]`.

`array[16]` does not represent a 2D array but rather a 1D array.

Here is an image which demonstrates the array structure

[image]

Comment: Very pretty diagram - certainly plus one - if a little misleading given that you have 5 rows.

Comment: @Bathsheba:- I have just taken it from the source: http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/2d-arrays-in-c-example/

Answer (score 0):

To declare a 2-D array only subscript notation is like arr[][] only.
2D array is only to simplify the accessing of elements,

Pointer expression of 2-D array:

```
the array name itself is a pointer to first sub array,

arr:
    will be pointer to first sub array, not the first element of first sub 
    array, according to relationship of array & pointer, it also represent 
    the array itself,

arr+1:
    will be pointer to second sub array(row), not the second element of first sub(row) 
    array,

*(arr+1):
    will be pointer to first element of second sub array(row),
    according to relationship of array & pointer, it also represent second sub array(row), same as arr[1],

*(arr+1)+2:
    will be pointer to third element of second sub array(row),

*(*(arr+1)+2):
    will get value of third element of second sub array(row),
    same as arr[1][2],
```